# Who and where is settled affinity mask per process?

Tags: centos, process, cpu, taskset

I have a process, shell. It's affinity mask is 1 (I have 3 CPUs)
On redundant machine (almost mirror - it is 7 - ALL CPUs)
Who is deciding which mask to set or where it is configured?

```
[root@h1-nms ~]# ps $$
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 7605 pts/2    Ss     0:00 -bash
[root@h1-nms ~]# taskset -p $$
pid 7605's current affinity mask: 1
```

Comment: `bash(7605)───pstree(21743)`

Comment: with `- p`. `-s` give error (`pstree: invalid option -- 's'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that on a specific machine affinity was managed by Cgroups (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)